# Unable to access SSRS Web Portal via URL

Tags: reporting-services

I set up my SSRS Server to be accessed via a domain instead of using the server. I am accessing the Web Portal as https://subdomain.domain.com/ instead of http://SERVERNAME/Report Server. I can access the Web Portal if I use the SERVERNAME. I can use my Windows Credentials to access the Web Portal and open/run reports. However, when I try to access the Web Portal via domain address, the login prompt shows, I type in my credentials, and the login prompt shows again. In the console, I see that it is returning this error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()`

I am trying to access the Web Portal on the same box. I don't know if that makes any difference.

My SSRS/Windows skills are rudimentary at best. I am not sure how to troubleshoot this or what else to try. Any suggestions on how to access the SSRS Web Portal using the web address instead of using the server name.